# Adding a where clause like '%%' cause any performance issues?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I am writing a query which will be executed on a database through my program. In that query I am adding a `where` clause with the values that I send from the client. In the case where some values are not there, I am leaving it blank (i.e it will look like `select * from tablename where columname like '%%' and columname1 like '%%'`). Could this cause any performance issues?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Would it be complicated to check for the content and build the query depending on that condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to answer such a question is by testing.  You should try the query with and without the condition.

Adding conditions to a `where` clause can impact performance in at least three ways:

- Conditions can make it more difficult for the optimizer to use an index (or choose appropriate partitions) for the query.
- Conditions can change the "selectivity" of tables.  If the optimizer does not know the number of rows being selected, then it might choose a less efficient algorithm for joins and aggregations.
- It might be expensive to evaluate the condition itself.

If your query is simple:

```
select t.*
from t
where col like '%%';
```

Then the first two points are not relevant.  The third is slightly relevant.  The question is whether the database "optimizes" away the `like` (because the pattern is generic).  I don't think it does; it would have to replace it with `col is not null`.

There is some overhead to using `like`.  I would speculate that the overhead for `like` is much less than the overhead for reading the table in the first place.  So, although it might affect performance, in a simple case, the effect would be relatively small.